# Does a Pendulum do more work than what's going into it?

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, newtonian-gravity, work, potential-energy

During the process of a pendulum swinging it is performing work done in between potential and kinetic energy on a continuous basis as long as a small force, *small amount of work*, is continuously supplied to it.

For instance let's say that there is an initial amount of energy used in lifting the 10 pound bob from it's resting position, at the very bottom of the pendulum, all the way up to the left side and then releasing it.

The 10 pound bob now begins oscillating back and forth with a continued supply of small pushing forces to keep it up. Once it has reached it's highest energetic state (*height*) with the smallest possible pushing forces it is then considered to be in *resonance*.

During this state of resonance with the pendulum and it's 10 pound bob being oscillated back and forth with a small pushing force, the heavy 10 pound bob is being lifted twice, once going forward and then once on the way back.

Figure out how much energy would it take to lift this 10 pounds of mass twice. It would be a whole lot more than a single small pushing force once it has achieved resonance, or the highest swinging height at the lowest input pushes.

**The question is:**

Is this scenario of the process of being in resonance, *highest height and lowest input energy*, showing us that more work is being done inside and/or outside of the pendulum than what is going into the pendulum? The process of the pendulum in full resonance is what is being referred to.

If so what kind of work is being done and is it inside or outside of the pendulum?

Comment: "It appears that work is constantly being performed..." - do you mean to say that _"work is constantly being performed __by gravity__"_?

Comment: What I mean is work is constantly being performed by gravity 'and' the mass of the pendulum against gravity. So all total work is included between the interchange between the potential and kinetic energy of both the work done by the mass of the pendulum as well as the work done by gravity.

Comment: Mass is a scalar quantity and performs no work. Pendulum bob is __never__ -
 during its entire motion - doing work on _itself_. The only two forces actually acting on it are tension by string and gravity. Tension does no work since bob's displacement is perpendicular to it. So, the only work on the bob is work by gravity .

Comment: The pendulum bob may not be doing work on itself, but it is doing work up and against gravity is it not? Work is force x distance.  A force is mass x acceleration. As for deceleration it is not at all clear if this constitutes work or not unless it is work being taken out of the system.

Comment: There never is truly a closed system as long as matter radiates or absorbs photons.

Answer (score 0):

Let's clear up our concepts here:

An object of some definite mass **never** does work on *any* other mass. Only forces can do work on an object. So, saying that the "...pendulum bob does work..." is meaningless.

You're trying to think in the right direction but are garbling the terminology and applying it to the wrong situation. The statement "The pendulum bob...is doing work up and against gravity" is meaningless, as explained above. Let me relate to you a more correct scenario:

**When does a force do work *against gravity*?**

When you lift a suitcase from the floor to a vertical height $h$, then the force exerted by your hands does positive work on the suitcase, and this work is done against the force of gravity.

---

**What about the closed/open system?**

A particular force becomes *internal* for a system of two bodies *only* when it is applied equal and opposite on both the bodies by Newton's Third law. The correct expression for the force of gravity is actually $F=Gm_1m_2/r^2$ which is internal only to a system of the object (pendulum bob) and the earth (both taken together). If the earth exerts a force of $1N$ on the pendulum bob, then the pendulum bob also exerts a gravitational force of $1N$ on the earth, which is reactionary, hence equal and opposite.

Comment: According to the answer down below this one, it is being said that a mass is indeed doing work on another mass which has been referred to as mass-Earth gravitational system. Similar to how magnets work, when they attract each other work is being done is it not? Yes it takes an equal amount of work to pull them apart, but it's still work that's been done regardless.  When a mass or object accelerates, because of another mass constitutes work regardless if it's done on another mass or not, but can be the result of another mass.

Comment: @MarcStriebeck Checking now, that answer has now since been deleted. I do not know from where you picked up that theory, but it's wrong. A mass can only exert force on another mass (gravitational), but the work that is done is done only due to the gravitational force. Think of it this way. The work done does NOT solely depend on the mass of the body. It also depends on the separation between the two bodies. In fact, the work done actually depends on the _force_ between the two bodies. In short, actually the __force__ is doing work, while the mass is only exerting force.

Comment: Ok so the forces are doing the work, I get that. So the point being is, is there more overall work being done inside the pendulum than the work done is pushing the pendulum intermittently?

Comment: Please define work being done "inside" the pendulum. What do you mean by that?

Comment: By work being done inside the pendulum I mean just that, as there is a constant energy exchange alternating between kinetic and potential in which neither one is constant, but always changing, which from my understanding constitutes work being done, but I could be wrong.

Comment: Yes, if change of PE into KE (or vc-vs) occurs, we can certainly conclude that external forces are are doing work (by Work-energy theorem). [But, you can NOT call it work being done "inside" the pendulum] However, the *total energy* (PE+KE) of a pendulum bob - once released - *is conserved throughout its entire motion*. (look up the internet/textbook, you'll find loads of illustrations for this) Also, this is exactly equal to the amount of work you did initially - in pushing the pendulum bob up to a certain height - after which it began its motion.

Comment: Hi, are you sure you answered this correctly? For instance take a pendulum with a 10 pound bob being oscillated back and forth with a small pushing force. The heavy 10 pound bob is being lifted *twice*, once going forward and then once on the way back. Figure out how much energy would it take to lift this 10 pounds of mass twice? It would be a whole lot more than a single small pushing force right?  Perhaps I should have included that the pendulum was already in the process of swinging at it's highest state. I understand that the conservation of the of it's energy is only equal to the initial

Comment: From the words "is being lifted twice" and "pushing the pendulum intermittently" I understood the situation as 1) the bob is initially at rest at mean position. 2) you give it a small push to the right/left 3) it starts oscillating. Note that once the pendulum starts oscillating, it will NOT stop (assuming ideal conditions - without air resistance)

Comment: I have a problem apparently of wording things, but yes initially the pendulum is first raised, but I am more interested with the steady state process of it *already* in the swinging process. By it will NOT stop I was meaning because it has a continuous small pushing force on it. So sorta like freeze framing it and then taking a snap shot or pausing the process as it's occurring and as the pendulum is swinging at its fullest and highest state of swinging energy.

Comment: Yes, the pendulum only stops *momentarily* at the highest point of its motion. That's right.

Comment: @Guarang Tandon - So all that needs to be known is that during any one point in time *as the swing is at its fullest swing* with the input pushing force at its lowest energy, (*optimized or resonance*) Would it help to reword the question a little bit?

Comment: Please reword your question. Please do.

Comment: @Guarang Tandon: **You wrote** "*In short, actually the force is doing work, while the mass is only exerting force*". If the mass is exerting a force, and if force is doing work, wouldn't the mass exerting the force be doing work then? Or are those two processes completely separate from each other? In other words how exactly is the mass exerting a force connected to the force doing work? It just sounds like that the work done is ultimately the result of the mass exerting the force and that the work is directly connected to the mass. Or is it not directly connected? Is it more indirectly?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/68146/discussion-between-gaurang-tandon-and-marc-striebeck).